# Expansion of factorial as linear combination of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, factorial

Let $k \leq n$ be positive integers. I would like a proof of the following identity:

$$
n!=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (-1)^{n-k} k^n.
$$

EDIT: For context, I am using this to verify the below polarization identity for writing the multilinear form $\overline{Q}$ associated to a degree-$k$ homogeneous polynomial $Q$ (Equation taken from Landsberg's book Tensors:Geometry and Applications). In particular, I need to verify this identity in order to show that the proposed multilinear form $\overline{Q}$ agrees with the polynomial $Q$, i.e. that $\overline{Q}(v,\dots, v)=Q(v)$ for all $v$ in the underlying vector space.

[image]

I verified my desired identity in Mathematica, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Shaun Done. Thanks

Comment: I checked and I get $n!$ in both cases... Can you check again?

Comment: To Ben: You're right, my apologies, I made clerical mistakes.  I deleted my previous comment.